# Use Lambda to load a non-string object from S3 to perform computation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lda, serverless-framework

I'm doing test development on how to use Lambda and S3 together with other possible AWS services to create a web service.

The background is to use a LDA model constructed using Gensim to analyse a text file that exist in S3. And the goal is to use Lambda's event trigger to automatically analyse texts that gets uploaded into the S3 bucket.

So far I have tried to create simple functions in Lambda to print and log an items properties when it gets uploaded to S3 bucket. However the analysis is an issue because of the LDA model is required to perform the analysis.

I can extract objects in S3 using the key by essentially calling:

```
s3resource = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3resource.Object(BucketName, Key)
response = obj.get()
data = response['Body'].read()
```

However that makes the data variable as string. I need to extract the metadata so it can be loaded into a model object. So more in the style of:

```
model = obj.get()...
```

First:
Is this possible? Loading a model file around 200-300mb into memory in Lambda to perform tasks?

Second:
Since this task should be invoked repeatedly for each file, my logic tells me to find ways to store the model in persistent memory to save fetch time... Is it possible to do more efficient object passing elsewhere?

P.S. to perform the analysis the required parameters are: the model, a wordid dict, the actual text that needs to be analysed.

Any help would be much appreciated and if there is an better fitting alternative, that would also be really awesome.

Thanks.